# How to autoplay video for React video MUI component on iPhone

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone, material-ui

It is working well on Chrome/Firefox for Desktop and Android.

But it is not working for only iPhone.

```
<Box
    component="video"
    sx={{
        width: "100vw",
        height: "calc(100vh - 80px)",
        objectFit: "cover",
    }}
    muted
    loop
    autoPlay
>
```